# Retrieve and loop through Story Ranges from Word OLE using Embarcadero C++ (Builder)

Tags: c++, vba, ms-word, c++builder, ole

I have a code snippet which loops through a list of hyperlink (file link) objects (members `anchor` and `destination`) and inserts them into a selected Word document.  I can search the Word document and insert the hyperlink when it finds the target (anchor) string. I would now like to loop through all the `StoryRanges` in the Word document to ensure that no sections is missed. I can get the number of story ranges, e.g., using `WordApplication1->ActiveDocument->StoryRanges->Count`.  However, I can't pass the parameter in the correct form to actually retrieve the story range I want to search next, e.g. `WordApplication1->ActiveDocument->StoryRanges->Item`.  I have a numeric count but `Item` expects as a parameter a VBA constant with the correct type.  What am I missing?

**Edit** Here is  the code.  The line causing the problem is

```
wdFootnotesStoryID = WordApplication1->ActiveDocument->StoryRanges->Item(??????)->get_ID();
```

I previously tried to typing parameters as int, OleVariant.  The error message for OleVariant was did not match the parameter expected. I used wdFootnotesStory in an attempt to reference the enum but that came up as not defined. I tried Int values as well.

Here is the OLESafe enum - defined in Word_2k.h

```
enum class WdStoryType
{
  wdMainTextStory = 1, 
  wdFootnotesStory = 2, 
  wdEndnotesStory = 3, 
  wdCommentsStory = 4, 
  wdTextFrameStory = 5, 
  wdEvenPagesHeaderStory = 6, 
  wdPrimaryHeaderStory = 7, 
  wdEvenPagesFooterStory = 8, 
  wdPrimaryFooterStory = 9, 
  wdFirstPageHeaderStory = 10, 
  wdFirstPageFooterStory = 11
};
```

Here is the main code.
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop

#include "Main.h"

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma link "Word_2K_SRVR"
#pragma resource "*.dfm"

struct THyperLink
{
    String Anchor;
    String FilePath;
};

TList* linkList = new TList;

TForm1 *Form1;


//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
    THyperLink* link = new THyperLink;
    link->Anchor = "ABC.0001.0002.0003";
    link->FilePath = "S:\\Development\\WordLinking\\Test\\ABC.0001.0002.0003.pdf";
    linkList->Add(link);

    THyperLink* link2 = new THyperLink;
    link2->Anchor = "ABC.0001.0002.0004";
    link2->FilePath = "S:\\Development\\WordLinking\\Test\\ABC.0001.0002.0004.pdf";
    linkList->Add(link2);
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{

    OleVariant Template = EmptyParam();
    OleVariant NewTemplate = False;
    OleVariant ItemIndex = 1;
    OleVariant strToInsert = "Insert String";
    OleVariant endOfLine = "TEST";
    OleVariant wdStory = 6;
    //OleVariant wdMove = 0;
    OleVariant rng;

    OleVariant strSearch;// = "ABC.0001.0002.0003";
    OleVariant strLink; // = "S:Development\\WordLinking\\Test\\ABC.0001.0002.0003.pdf";
    OleVariant lnkDoc = "S:\\Development\\WordLinking\\Test\\ZZZ.0001.0002.0003.docx";

    OleVariant wdCharacter = "wdCharacter";
    OleVariant cChars = 18;
    OleVariant wdMove = "wdMove";
    OleVariant wdTrue = true;

    OleVariant wrdStoryRangeCount;
    OleVariant wdFootnotesStoryID;
    OleVariant rangeStory;
    OleVariant wrdDoc;

    WdStoryType wdFootnotesStory = 2;


    try
    {
        WordApplication1->Connect();

    }
    catch (...)
    {
        ShowMessage("Microsoft word is not installed");
    }



    //Make application visible
    WordApplication1->GetDefaultInterface()->Visible = True;

    //Open document to be linked
    WordApplication1->Documents->Open(lnkDoc);

    //Open new document - add to document collection in application
    //WordApplication1->Documents->Add(Template, NewTemplate);

    //go to top of the document
    WordApplication1->Selection->HomeKey(wdStory);

    for (int index = 0; index <= linkList->Count-1; index++)
    {
        //Retrieve hyperlink object
        THyperLink* link = reinterpret_cast<THyperLink*>(linkList->Items[index]);
        strSearch = (OleVariant)link->Anchor;
        strLink = (OleVariant)link->FilePath;

        //
        wrdStoryRangeCount = WordApplication1->ActiveDocument->StoryRanges->Count;

        //WordApplication1->ActiveDocument->StoryRanges->Item(1);

        wdFootnotesStoryID = WordApplication1->ActiveDocument->StoryRanges->Item(??????)->get_ID();
        ShowMessage ("wdFootnotesStory ID: " + wdFootnotesStoryID);

        //WordApplication1->ActiveDocument->get_

        while (WordApplication1->Selection->Find->Execute(strSearch,Template,Template,Template,Template,Template,wdTrue))
        //while (WordApplication1->ActiveDocument->StoryRanges->Item(wdFootnotesStory)->Find->Execute(strSearch,Template,Template,Template,Template,Template,wdTrue))
        {
            WordApplication1->Selection->Hyperlinks->Add(WordApplication1->Selection->Range,strLink,Template,Template,strSearch,Template);
        }

        //go back to top of Word document
        WordApplication1->Selection->HomeKey(wdStory);
    }

    //Disconnect from word
    WordApplication1->Disconnect();

}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Solution**: In the course of adding the code, I think I stumbled across the solution - `WdStoryType::wdFootnotesStory`.  It appears all I was missing was the class qualifier reference.

Comment: This isn't Embarcadero-specific --- it's almost as much of a pain in VBA!  See [this MVP article](http://word.mvps.org/faqs/customization/ReplaceAnywhere.htm).  (PS - welcome to the site!)

Comment: Many thanks CXWfor the answer and welcome.  I have that article and I appreciate its going to be a bit of a journey. I guess my real question atm is - How do I pass a WdStoryType Index parameter as part of the WordApplication1->ActiveDocument->StoryRanges->Item() call from C++ in Embarcadero.  It is unhappy with an OleVariant.  I am clearly not fully getting how to pass parameters in OLE calls.

Comment: This is early binding and WdStoryType is an enum declared in Word_2K.h.  For now, I just want to pass the value wdFootnotesStory = 2.  I have tried a number of variations using an OleVariant wrapper but can't get it to work.  I am clearly not getting how to pass enum parameters in OLE calls. Cheers.

Comment: Would you please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38104339/edit) to include the code you've tried, and what errors you got (compile or run-time)?  I don't know the answer off-hand, but maybe seeing what *doesn't* work will give me (or another reader) some ideas.  Also, posting the key bits of what you have so far is considered good etiquette on SO. See the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) page.  Thanks! --- One other thought - per [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc237562.aspx), maybe a `VARIANT` `VT_I4`?

Comment: Or [this](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/radstudio2007/RS2007_helpupdates/HUpdate4/EN/html/devwin32/casmarshalingdata_xml.html), which says use pull in the type library and use `Integer`.  (From Google results for `ole automation enum type embarcadero`.)

Comment: Thanks CXW for all your help with this one.  I had a good look at the links you sent through.  Any other comments would be appreciated.  I have a lot to learn.

Comment: Happy to help!  Please move the solution from the bottom of your question to a new answer.  Then, in a few days when the system will let you, hit the checkmark to accept that answer.  That way the question will be cleared off  the Unanswered lists, and it will be easier for others to benefit from what you've learned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: In the course of adding the code, I think I stumbled across the solution - WdStoryType::wdFootnotesStory. It appears all I was missing was the class qualifier reference.